# How does Apache Kafka use open file descriptors?

Tags: apache-kafka

I wanted to know how does Kafka use open file descriptors. Why is it recommended to have a large number of open file descriptor. Does it impact Producer and Consumer throughput.

Answer (score 4):

Brokers create and maintain file handles for each log segment files and network connections. The total number could be very huge if the broker hosts many partitions and partition has many log segment files. This applies for the network connection as well.

I don't immediately see any possible performance declines caused by setting a large `file-max`, but the page cache miss matters.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka keeps one file descriptor open for every segment file, and it fails miserably if the limit is too low. I don't know if it affects consumer throughput, but I assume it doesn't since Kafka appears to ignore the limit until it is reached.

The number of segment files is the number of partitions multiplied by some number that is dependent on the retention policy. The default retention policy is to start a new segment after one week (or 1GB, whatever occurs first) and to delete a segment when all data in it is more than one week old.

(*disclaimer: This answer is for Kafka 1.0 based on what I have learnt from one installation I have*)

Answer (score 1):

We can check in below ways.

if a broker hosts many partitions. For example, a Kafka broker needs at least the following number of file descriptors to just track log segment files:

(number of partitions)*(partition size / segment size)